# Java removes a slash from path and later gives me NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, hadoop, path, java.nio.file, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to write in Hadoop HDFS, using this line of code:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("hdfs:////localhost:9000/user/cloudera/trial/"+ "cat.txt","miao miao!".getBytes());
```

The Spark Application gives me  this exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: hdfs:/quickstart.cloudera:9000/user/cloudera/trial/cat2
```

Which, I am interpreting,  gives an error because there is only one slash after "hdfs:" .
I remember I had already used the java.nio.Files methods to write in HDFS, so I would exclude that is the problem.
What should I do to prevent that exception?

EDIT: The import section

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
```

Comment: Please Show the Import statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you can not use java.nio.Files to write to HDFS. Java classes don´t know about the NameNode and DataNodes in hadoop cluster. You need to use hadoop libraries to communicate with HDFS.

Here I have an example to write to HDFS using Java:

https://github.com/lalosam/HadoopInExamples/blob/master/src/main/java/rojosam/utils/hdfs/CreateTestsFiles.java